# newtons law of cooling with decreasing ambient temperature

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A cup of hot coffee initially at $90$ C cools to $80$ C in five minutes while sitting in a room of temperature $20$ C. Determine when the temperature of the coffee is $50$ C given that the room temperature is decreasing at the rate of $1$ C.

How do you alter $T = (T_o-M) e^{(-kt)}$ + M to accomodate the decreasing room temperature??? I was given the hint $\frac{dT}{dt} = K[20 - t -T]$. Why $\frac{dT}{dt}$? I figured you would need to find dM/dt since its the rate of the ambient temperature M that is decreasing

Comment: It seems you are given $\frac{dM}{dt}$. "given that the room temperature is decreasing at the rate of 1 C"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Newton's law of cooling as
$$
\dot{T} = K (T_R - T) = 
K \left(20- t - T\right)
$$
where $T_R$ is the room temperature and $T$ the coffee temperature.
This gives
\begin{align}
\dot{T} + K T 
&= 
K \left( 20 - t \right) \iff \\
e^{Kt}\left[\dot{T} + K T\right] 
&= 
e^{Kt} K \left( 20  - t \right) \iff \\
\frac{d}{dt} \left( e^{Kt}T \right) 
&=
K e^{Kt} \left( 20 - t \right) \iff \\
T
&=
T_0 e^{-Kt} + K e^{-Kt} \int\limits_0^t e^{K\tau} \left( 20 - \tau \right) d\tau \\
&= 
T_0 e^{-Kt} + K e^{-Kt}\left[20 \,e^{K\tau} +e^{K\tau}\frac{1-K\tau}{K^2} \right]_0^t \\
&=
T_0 e^{-Kt} + 20\left(1 - \,e^{-Kt}\right) +
\frac{1}{K}\left(1-Kt- e^{-Kt}\right) \\
  &=
(20 - t) + \frac{1}{K} + \left(T_0 - 20 -\frac{1}{K}\right) e^{-Kt}
\end{align}

We know $T(0) = 90$ and $T(5) = 80$:
$$
80 = 15 + \frac{1}{K} + \left(70-\frac{1}{K}\right) e^{-5K}
$$
I see only a numerical solution, which gives: $K = 0.0296568$ ([via WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+80+%3D+15+%2B1%2Fx+%2B+%2870-1%2Fx%29*exp%28-5*x%29+for+x)).

This could be used to solve $T(t) = 50$ for $t$.
Again using some numerical method this gives $t = 22.3937$ minutes ([via WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+50+%3D+%2820-x%29+%2B1%2F%280.0296568%29+%2B+%2870-1%2F%280.0296568%29%29*exp%28-x*%280.0296568%29%29+for+x)).
Otherwise we could have read it from the [cooling curve](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%2820-x%29+%2B1%2F%280.0296568%29+%2B+%2870-1%2F%280.0296568%29%29*exp%28-x*%280.0296568%29%29+from+0+to+30+with+grid).

Trying to verify the solution

The cooling rate is:
$$
\dot{T} = -\left( 1 + \left[ K(T_0 -20)-1 \right] e^{-Kt} \right)
$$
Plotting a graph of $\dot{T}/K+T$ gave $20-t$.

Comment: Can you explain your usage of \tau here, and why it is necessary? Are you integrating both sides of the equation here?

Comment: Yes, both sides are integrated from $\tau=0$ to $\tau=t$. $\tau$ is just some name for the integration over the time variable, chosen different from the end time $t$ to avoid using the same name twice.